React Native won't connect to Socket IO
I'm using this code to connect to Socket:
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import client, { Socket } from "socket.io-client";
import { env } from "../constants/env";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";

interface SocketContextType {
  socket: Socket | null;
}

const SocketContext = createContext({ socket: null } as SocketContextType);

const socketConfig = {
  jsonp: false,
  autoConnect: false,
  secure:true,
  // path: env.SOCKET_PATH,
  transports: ["websocket"],
};

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};
export default function SocketProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const socket = useRef(client('https://socket-dev.com', socketConfig));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) return;

    socket.current.auth = {
      id_instituicao: user?.id_instituicao,
      usuario: user?.user,
      ambiente: "app",
    };

    console.log(socket.current)

    socket.current.connect();

    socket.current.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Conectado");
    });

    socket.current.on("connect_error", (error) => {
      console.log("Erro de conexão:", error);
    });

    socket.current.on("disconnect", (msg) => {
      console.log("SocketIO: Disconnect", msg);
      socket.current = client('https://socket-dev.com', socketConfig);
    });

    return () => {
      if (socket && socket.current) {
        socket?.current?.removeAllListeners();
        socket?.current?.close();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket: socket.current }}>
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useSocket = () => useContext(SocketContext);

export { useSocket };

But I'm get this error code: Unable to resolve host \"socket-dev.com\": No address associated with hostname
const socketConfig = {
  jsonp: false,
  autoConnect: false,
  secure:true,
  path: env.SOCKET_PATH,
  transports: ["websocket"],
};
...
const socket = useRef(client(env.SOCKET_URL, socketConfig));

I was trying to connect with the socket on my node server, like this:
But received: Unable to resolve host \"undefined": No address associated with hostname
And if I entered the URL directly, the app would crash with the message: Invalid URL PORT: 5000
I have one electron app and one web app connected to my local socket normally
I have the permission set on my AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
and i'm using "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5"

what is your SOCKET URL =

i'm trying to use 'https://socket-dev.com' but my local socket is: http://192.168.1.250:5000

Try deploy the code in live server having a ssl certificate (https). It might not work on local
